# Get a multiple-index column values

Tags: pandas, indexing

Let's assume we have a *DataFrame* *df* with *N* rows:

```
| multiple-index |  | ordinary columns |
I_A, I_B, I_C, I_D,  C_A, C_B, C_C, C_D
```

How can we extract all *N* values for *I_B* index column? *df.index* gives us all combinations of *I_A...I_D* but it is not what we need. Of course, we can iterate over it but it will cost productivity, there must be an easier, more straightforward way?

Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE**

E.g., we have *df* generated by:

```
data = {
    "animal": ["cat", "dog", "parrot", "hamster"],
    "size":   ["big", "big", "small", "small"],
    "feet":   [4, 4, 2, 4]
}

multi = pd.DataFrame(data)

multi.set_index(["size", "feet"], inplace = True)
```

and which is:

```
              animal
 size feet |
  big    4 |     cat
  big    4 |     dog
small    2 |  parrot
small    4 | hamster
```

Its index is:

```
MultiIndex([(  'big', 4),
            (  'big', 4),
            ('small', 2),
            ('small', 4)],
           names=['size', 'feet'])
```

from which we would like to get all sizes:

```
['big', 'big', 'small', 'small']
```

How can we do that?

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame object for clarity? The is no such thing as mixed MultiIndex and normal index, it's necessarily all MultiIndex. What is the output of `df.index`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html):

```
multi.index.get_level_values('size')
```

Output: `Index(['big', 'big', 'small', 'small'], dtype='object', name='size')`

Or as list:

```
multi.index.get_level_values('size').to_list()
```

Output: `['big', 'big', 'small', 'small']`

Comment: Thanks! That is precisely what was needed!